# latex and listings: highlighting some parts of the code

Tags: latex

I'm using Latex and the `listings` package to display some C++ code (with syntax highlighting) inside a document.

I need to highlight some parts of the code. This specific highlight has nothing to do with syntax highlighting, it's just some parts of the code I'd like to highlight so that the reader can focus on it.

I wish I could make some variable name, for instance, displaying in bold, and on a yellow background. Here is something I did with MSWord I'd like to reproduce with Latex (of course, not the red and green underlining):

[image]
.

I haven't found a way to do it with the `listings` package. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable arbitrary LaTeX commands inside your `listings` region:

```
\begin{listings}[escapeinside=\{\}]
{\highlight{Colonnes[3] = 9}}
\end{listings}
```

`\highlight` is your highlighting macro (you need to write it yourself). See the listings documentation, section 4.14 (“Escaping to LaTeX”) for further details. Notice that you now need to escape every other occurrence of the special characters in your code – so for C++ code, `{}` is probably a bad choice.

Comment: Thanks for the hint ! I couldn't make it work using `escapeinside` (don't know why, got error I didn't understand), but made it work with `escapechar=\%`.

For the record, I defined the `\highlight` macro this way :

\newcommand\highlight[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}

using the package `xcolor`.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately [@Konrad's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771799/latex-and-listings-highlighting-some-parts-of-the-code/2771832#2771832) truly escapes from `listings` formatting entirely. If the highlighted text contains any program keywords, then those keywords will not be highlighted by the `listings` package as they would be on non-highlighted lines. The ideal might be to use `\highlight{\lstinline{...}}`, but it seems you cannot nest a `\lstinline` macro inside a `listings` environment.

The TeX StackExchange site has [essentially the same question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15237/highlight-text-in-code-listing-while-also-keeping-syntax-highlighting), with a [nice answer based on the tikz package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15237/highlight-text-in-code-listing-while-also-keeping-syntax-highlighting/15257#15257) and a [further refinement thereof](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15237/highlight-text-in-code-listing-while-also-keeping-syntax-highlighting/18890#18890).  It overlays highlighting while still letting `listings` automatically format highlighted text.

This whole `tikz`-based approach [took on a life of its own](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19242/how-to-draw-text-anchored-tikz-line-below-text-instead-of-above), eventually leading to a [good, robust solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19242/how-to-draw-text-anchored-tikz-line-below-text-instead-of-above/19716#19716).  That is currently the best known (to me) approach to highlighting selected `listings` lines while keeping automatic syntax highlighting.  It will actually work just as well for stroking highlights between *any* pair of locations on a given page.

Answer (score 4):

In C or C++ code, I think the character **`** is free to be the escape character.

```
lstset {
...
escapeinside=\`\`,
...
}
```

then, you can use it like

```
\begin{lstlisting}
const_cast<T>(`\it{exception}`)
\end{lstlisting}
```

the word `exception` then become *exception*. BTW, character **`** is the Markdown format
character for code, so its very easy to use it in C or C++ like code listing.